# PyCharm (2019): How to get rid of the file size/date infomration in the project tree?

Tags: pycharm

I have no idea how I got to seeing file date and sizes. But I want to remove this mode and see filenames only. I can't find any documentation on how to do that, nor setting option to control this.

Anyone?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Project tool window allows you to see the size and modification timestamp for the files in the project tree. To display this information, from the main menu, select View | Appearance | Descriptions in Tree Views.